# Laravel Menu Logic

Tags: html, arrays, menu, laravel-4

I retrieve menu items from database which they have parent - child relationship and I would like to create a nested list. To create the nested list it needs to be included in a reclusive iteration which creates a multidimensional array. Now I'm at the point to figure out where to loop this array should I loop in view or should be created in my repository with all necessary HTML markup ?

My problem how do I handle recursive iteration in Laravel Blade

Comment: Can you provide a example of the object being passed to the view

Comment: Maybe it's better to prepare the multidimensional array (recursive function) in the controller/model and iterate it in the view as @Josh suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be iterating over it in the html template (using blade syntax)

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
<p>This is user {{ $user->id }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Source: [Laravel templating](http://laravel.com/docs/templates)